# MySQL 8 taking 1000x times longer to execute this query vs 5.7 when ORDER BY is used

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, order-by, orm

This query comes from an ORM (Laravel Eloquent) on a WordPress database. I upgraded to MySQL 8 from 5.7 (AWS RDS), and the performance went from pretty speedy to basically broken. API requests that previously took ~50ms were now taking 30-60 *seconds* to execute. It was so bad I thought it was a DB connection issue at first.

I used Laravel Telescope to diagnose and one particular type of query stood out immediately (see below).

I then discovered that if I removed the `order by`, the issue went away completely! (Incidentally, if I removed the big subquery, the query was also fast).

The query:

```
select
  *
from
  `wp_posts`
where
  `post_type` = 'post'
  and exists (
    select
      *
    from
      `wp_term_taxonomy`
      inner join `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id`
    where
      `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id`
      and `taxonomy` = 'tax_channel'
      and exists (
        select
          *
        from
          `wp_terms`
        where
          `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id` = `wp_terms`.`term_id`
          and `slug` in ('news')
      )
  )
  and (`post_status` = 'publish')

order by `wp_posts`.`post_date` desc

limit 2 offset 0
```

**`explain` results for 8.0: (takes ~30-90 seconds)**

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_terms |  | ref | PRIMARY,slug | slug | 766 | const | 2 | 100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_term_taxonomy |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,term_id_taxonomy,taxonomy | term_id_taxonomy | 138 | wordpress.wp_terms.term_id,const | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_term_relationships |  | ref | PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id | term_taxonomy_id | 8 | wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id | 238 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_posts |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type_status_date | PRIMARY | 8 | wordpress.wp_term_relationships.object_id | 1 | 50.00 | Using where; End temporary |

**`Explain` results for 5.7 (takes ~50ms)**

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | wp_posts |  | ref | type_status_date | type_status_date | 164 | const,const | 176172 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wp_term_relationships |  | ref | PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id | PRIMARY | 8 | wordpress.wp_posts.ID | 3 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wp_term_taxonomy |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,taxonomy | PRIMARY | 8 | wordpress.wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id | 1 | 5.00 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wp_terms |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,slug | PRIMARY | 8 | wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy.term_id | 1 | 5.00 | Using where |

**`Explain` results for 8.0 with `order by` removed (takes ~50ms)**

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_terms |  | ref | PRIMARY,slug | slug | 766 | const | 2 | 100.00 | Using where; Start temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_term_taxonomy |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,term_id_taxonomy,taxonomy | term_id_taxonomy | 138 | wordpress.wp_terms.term_id,const | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_term_relationships |  | ref | PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id | term_taxonomy_id | 8 | wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id | 238 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | wp_posts |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type_status_date | PRIMARY | 8 | wordpress.wp_term_relationships.object_id | 1 | 50.00 | Using where; End temporary |

I am looking for advice on how to bring MySQL 8 performance up to the level of 5.7 with this query.

Or, a fix to the query that accomplishes the same thing. As I mentioned, this query is generated by an ORM (Eloquent) so I'm not sure how much control I have in changing the raw SQL.

Or maybe there's something I'm missing in MySQL options table?

Or, maybe I'm missing an index that could help besides the default WordPress keys?:

```
type_status_date    BTREE   FALSE   post_type,post_status,post_date,ID
post_parent_id  BTREE   FALSE   post_parent,ID
post_parent BTREE   FALSE   post_parent
post_name   BTREE   FALSE   post_name(191)
post_author BTREE   FALSE   post_author
PRIMARY BTREE   TRUE    ID
```

**EDIT:** I've rewritten the above query as a series of JOINs instead of subqueries, but it is just as slow:

```
select * from wp_posts 
inner join wp_term_relationships on wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
inner join wp_term_taxonomy on wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_terms on wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
where post_type = 'post'
and post_status = 'publish'
and slug in ('news')
order by post_date DESC
limit 2
```

**EDIT 2:**

It looks like the cause of the slowness is that MySQL 8 is choosing the `PRIMARY` index instead of `type_status_date`. If I force it to use the latter, then the query is pretty speedy (~100ms). Still twice as high as 5.7 but at least it's in the ballpark.

Because its an ORM writing this query, I dont think this solution is viable unfortunately.

So adding `/*+ index(wp_posts type_status_date) */` makes the query run in ~100ms instead of 30-90 seconds.

```
select /*+ index(wp_posts type_status_date) */
  *
from
  `wp_posts`

where
  `post_type` = 'post'
  and exists (
    select
      *
    from
      `wp_term_taxonomy`
      inner join `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id`
    where
      `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id`
      and `taxonomy` = 'tax_channel'
      and exists (
        select
          *
        from
          `wp_terms`
        where
          `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id` = `wp_terms`.`term_id`
          and `slug` in ('news')
      )
  )
  and (`post_status` = 'publish')
order by
  `wp_posts`.`post_date` desc
limit
  2 offset 0
```

Comment: Have you added the plugin [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: See if applying `ANALYZE TABLE` to each of the 4 tables helps.